# How to use semaphores without thread and fork?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm currently working on a school projet (C language) which aims to make processes who can write into shared memory, one by one.
I can't use multi-threading neither fork.
I can have **only one executable**, which must be run as many times as we want.

For example if i do : `./main john` then `./main toto`, John would be able to write in shared memory while Toto has to wait that John unlock the semaphore.

But I just can't find any documentation who explain clearly how it works **without doing threads, forks** etc.

May someone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: Search for libraries pthread.h and semaphore.h, basically you need to create two threads and put semaphores in critical regions (where threads can share a common variable). If you are using Linux you can type "man pthread" for example to get the manual of the library.

Comment: Title says without thread

Comment: Acquire an interprocess semaphore via `sem_open` if you can (and `semget` if you must).  Or acquire an exclusive, advisory file lock (`fcntl(F_SETLK)`/`lockf` or `flock`). Your professor probably disallowed threads to force you to consider _interprocess_ synchronization, and disallowed (explicit) forks to prevent you from easily _inheriting_ the interprocess semaphore (i.e., you must acquire it anew in each process).  Come back here if you have problems.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Linux is used:

Because multi-threading is not allowed, you may ignore pthread-semaphores.
Maybe system-V IPC semaphores are what you are looking for:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sysvipc.7.html

Those can be used between processes.

The system-V IPC also provides functions for shared memory handling.

Posix-semaphores and shm API are also another alternative:
https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Comment: As a small point, there aren't "pthread-semaphores."  pthreads _per se_ have mutexes, condition variables, barriers, and rwlocks, but not semaphores.  Though both `<semaphore.h>` and `<pthread.h>` are now part of the POSIX Base, they were previously part of different option groups.

Answer (score 0):

https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-storage has examples for using POSIX semaphores to synchronize shared memory access (in the second part of that article, past the file lock example).

It is not unlike synchronizing threads, except that it uses operating system facilities for inter process communication.

POSIX semaphores are available on POSIX systems, notably many *nixes.